# How to access the template through the controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to access the template through the controller in Angular Js

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean access the template?

Comment: He probably means how to manipulate the DOM...the answer is you don't.

Comment: In directive we have tampletUrl. The same thing I want for controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use ngInclude directive:

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl"  ng-include="yourTemplateURL">
```

And set url inside YourCtrl:

```
$scope.yourTemplateURL= 'partials/template.html';
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude